# Calculate the elapsed time in seconds from date with 'HH:MM:SS' format ( MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to convert date in a string a vector of time, which as this format: 'HH:MM:SS', in a vector of time in seconds.It works well till a certain point and after it returns fake values.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
a={'596:30:18';'596:30:28';'596:30:38';'596:30:48';'596:30:58';'596:31:08';'596:31:18';'596:31:28';'596:31:38';'596:31:48';'596:31:58';'596:32:08';'596:32:18';'596:32:28';'596:32:38';'596:32:48';'596:32:58';'596:33:08'};

         formatIn = 'HH:MM:SS';
         DateVector = datevec(a(1:end,:),formatIn);
         time = etime(DateVector,DateVector(1,:));
```

It returns:

```
DateVector =

2017    1   25  20  30  18
2017    1   25  20  30  28
2017    1   25  20  30  38
2017    1   25  20  30  48
2017    1   25  20  30  58
2017    1   25  20  31  8
2017    1   25  20  31  18
2016    12  7   3   28  40,7040000000000
2016    12  7   3   28  50,7040000000000
2016    12  7   3   29  0,704000000000000
2016    12  7   3   29  10,7040000000000
2016    12  7   3   29  20,7040000000000
2016    12  7   3   29  30,7040000000000
2016    12  7   3   29  40,7040000000000
2016    12  7   3   29  50,7040000000000
2016    12  7   3   30  0,704000000000000
2016    12  7   3   30  10,7040000000000
2016    12  7   3   30  20,7040000000000
```

and

```
time =

0
10
20
30
40
50
60
-4294897,29600000
-4294887,29600000
-4294877,29600000
-4294867,29600000
-4294857,29600000
-4294847,29600000
-4294837,29600000
-4294827,29600000
-4294817,29600000
-4294807,29600000
-4294797,29600000
```

only the 7 firt value are correct. Anybody knows why is this happening?

Comment: You want a [`duration`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html), not a date.

Comment: I think your best method is actually splitting the string yourself and subtract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another way without loops and way faster (in theory):

```
B = regexp(a, ':', 'split');
C = vertcat(B{:});
D = str2double(C);  %D = cellfun(@str2num, C); also works but slower
```

this translates your time stamps to Hours:Minutes:Seconds in 3 columns, you can then quite easily subtract and get the time:

```
E =  bsxfun(@minus,D,D(1,:));
F = E(:,1)*3600 + E(:,2)*60 + E(:,3)

>>F =

 0
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
110
120
130
140
150
160
170
```

btw, what a strange datetime format.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed  it is a really strange datetime format :).

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation I can think of is that the `HH` identifier is not intendet to be used with 3-digits hours. Actually the [datevec documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) of datevec says

> HH - Hour in two digits format

So maybe, `'596:30:28'` is not a valid date string and you need to convert it to a different format, e.g. `'dd:HH:MM:SS'`.

This can be done like this (assuming that all hours are 3-digit numbers):

```
a={'596:30:18';'596:30:28';'596:30:38';'596:30:48';'596:30:58';'596:31:08';'596:31:18';'596:31:28';'596:31:38';'596:31:48';'596:31:58';'596:32:08';'596:32:18';'596:32:28';'596:32:38';'596:32:48';'596:32:58';'596:33:08'};

a_ddhhmmss = {};
for ii=1:length(a)
    datestring = a{ii};
    colon_indices = strfind(datestring, ':');  %check how many digits the hours have
    hours_digits = colon_indices(1)-1;
    hours = str2num(datestring(1:hours_digits));
    days = floor(hours/24) + 1; % start with day=1
    hours = rem(hours,24);
    a_ddhhmmss{end+1} = [num2str(days), ':', num2str(hours), datestring(4:end)];
end

formatIn = 'dd:HH:MM:SS';
DateVector = datevec(a_ddhhmmss(1:end,:),formatIn)
time = etime(DateVector,DateVector(1,:))
```

Of course, it still makes no sense that the behavior you observe just sets in between the dates `'596:30:18'` and `'596:30:28'`. Even if the `datevec` function is used out of scope, it should rather throw an error instead of returning meaningless output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to convert it in a 'dd:HH:MM:SS' format?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a suggestion how to convert it so the other format. If time goes on, this might run into the same limitation for days larger than 31, I don't know ...

Comment: But what do you actually want to achieve? If it is just about computing the difference beteween the dates in seconds, it might be easier to not use the `datevec` function, but directly compute the difference in hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: It works perfectly. I will use the time vector to perform some calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily by first converting `a` using [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html), subtracting the first time point, and converting to [seconds](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/seconds.html):

```
D = datetime(datenum(a), 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum');  % A datetime array
secElapsed = seconds(D-D(1))

secElapsed =

     0
    10
    20
    30
    40
    50
    60
    70
    80
    90
   100
   110
   120
   130
   140
   150
   160
   170
```